# Why do I no longer have the option to set my Apple TV as a home hub?

Tags: appletv

In earlier tvOS 11 betas, I still had the option to set my Apple TV as my home's hub. In the golden master/release, that option is no longer present and in the Home app it says I have no home hub.

What happened to this functionality?

<sup><sup><sup>Don't say it was to get more HomeKit sales.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Sign-out of your iCloud account and reboot the AppleTV.  Also, if you have an iPad or iPhone that has the home's hub, you might have to power those down first then do the AppleTV.  Those steps seem to help other people but YMMV.

Comment: @fsb That didn’t work for me.